# Converting range python code into a function

Tags: python

Im trying to convert this code into function but it dosent work .

```
start = int(input("Enter the start of range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: "))
sum=0
for num in range(start, end + 1):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        sum=sum+num
print(sum)
```

I tried this one but it dosent work and i dont understand the error

```
def range(start,end):
  s=0
  for num in range(start, end + 1):  
        if num % 2 == 0:
          s=s+num
        else:
            pass
    print(s)


 
start = int(input("Enter the start of range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: "))  
range(start,end)
```

Comment: What error do you face when you convert it into a function? Could you show the function you have written?

Comment: what are you trying to do with your function? Your function is finding the sum of the even numbers in that range

Comment: provide start, end as paramether in function and return sum from function

Comment: Please provide an example of a function you tried to write which does not work, to show that you put in some effort.

Comment: @AidaAdib please [edit] your question to add more details instead of commenting, especially if it's code. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. You need to ask a _specific_ question about your code. What happens when you try to run it? What were you expecting to happen? In your case, you're probably getting a recursion error because you named your function `range`, which shadows the inbuilt `range()` that you are using inside your function, creating an infinite recursion. Call your function something else. In general, shadowing builtin names is a bad idea.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes thanks i edited it .im new to this site .sorry

Comment: @Cameron yes im trying to find the sum of the even numbers in this range

Comment: @blurryroots yes thanks i edited it you can see the example now

Comment: @AidaAdib In python [range is a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). It would also help to post the error message you are talking about. I assume it has something todo with recusion, since your function range, calls itself repeatedly until the maximum stack height is reached.

Comment: @AidaAdib consider accepting the answer which helped.

Comment: @blurryroots yes thank you i will do this next time

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

```
def sum_range(start, end):
    numbers_sum = 0
    for num in range(start, end+1):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            numbers_sum += num
    return numbers_sum

start = int(input("Enter the start of range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: "))
print(sum_range(start,end))
```

Comment: yes thanks this works

Comment: Shadowing the builtin `sum`, even if it's for a local variable inside a function, is a bad idea

Comment: @PranavHosangadi what should i do then ?

Comment: Just replace variable `sum` with `addition` for example. I changed it in the code. Thanks @PranavHosangadi!

Answer (score 0):

```
def total():

    start = int(input("Enter the start of range: "))
    end = int(input("Enter the end of range: "))
    total=0

    for num in range(start, end + 1):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            total=total+num
        
    print(total)  



total()
```

Or:

```
def total(start, end):

    total=0

    for num in range(start, end + 1):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            total=total+num
        
    print(total)  



total(1, 6)
```

Do not use the "sum" as the name of a variable, 'sum' is a reserved keyword in python used for the sum() built-in function.

Comment: thanks for the tip about sum .i didnt know